# What happened to Exclude from Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfvc

I remember that in the past I was able to Exclude selected files from Source Control.  But now this is missing:

[image]

How do I get it back.  I want to exclude permanently, for example the photos folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature can now be found in the Pending Changes window:

You must first undo any pending changes on this item if there are any.

[image]

And you can [specify a `.tfignore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore) in your source control system to make TFS automatically ignore files (the above mentioned dialog will create or update this file through the UI)

Comment: I can't see the items in the photos folder under `Detected adds`.  I had earlier Included the photos folder to my VS project as I wanted it to be published.  There is now a + sign against every picture as I have not checked in yet.  I don't want the picture files in this folder to be added to source control as they are "data" and not code.

Comment: You need to "Undo Pending Changes" on this folder first. That will remove the "add" status. After that they should be in the "Detected Changes" list. rightclick the folder for that.

Comment: Thanks.  By Undo Pending Changes (even though these files have never been modified) the picture files disappeared from the Included Changes. I hope they stay that way forever.  TFS is the most cryptic and unnatural piece of software in the world.  That Detected Adds list have thousands of items from projects of years ago.

Comment: Those files match your workspace definition. They are on disk, but not in TFS and not in a `.tfignore` file. So Visual Studio detects them as possible changes. Scoping your workspace definition to match your exact project should help